# Django register ModelForm with Model

Tags: python, django, metaclass, modelform

I have several MyModels, all derived from the same MyBaseModel, and for each model there is also a MyModelForm derived from MyModelBaseForm.
Given a MyModelForm, I can access the related model through MyModelForm._meta.model.
What would be the easiest way to do the reverse: given a MyModel, get the corresponding MyModelForm?

The reason is I want to use duck typing in a view:

```
from django.db import models

def edit_view(request, my_model_name, pk=None):
    my_model = my_model_registry[my_model_name]
    instance = get_object_or_404(my_model, pk=pk) if pk else None
    my_model_form = my_model._meta.modelform 
    # or my_model_form = my_model_form_registry[my_model]
    form = my_model_form(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    return render(request, 'my_template', {'form': form, 'instance': instance})

my_model_registry = dict( (Model._meta.verbose_name, Model) for Model in
                          models.get_models() if issubclass(Model, MyBaseModel)
                          )
```

The ideal solution would be to have a dictionary `my_model_form_registry[my_model]` so that I can look up the form just like I do with the model. I know I can do this manually, by explicitly setting

```
my_model_form_registry[MyModelForm._meta.model] = MyModelForm
```

after each MyModelForm definition, but in the spirit of DRY, I would like to do this once for the ModelBaseForm and have it executed automatically for all derived models.

Metaclasses can do this, but I can not get this to work because model.ModelForm already has a special metaclass.

Another option would be if there were an equivalent to `models.get_models`, but for modelforms. Does that exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`modelform_factory()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-factory) function in `django.forms.models` which dynamically constructs a ModelForm class given a model class, which sounds like it could do what you want.

Comment: This would work for simple model forms, but in my case I want the model forms to derive from MyModelBaseForm for some additional functionality, defined in clean_field and clean methods.

Comment: As that link shows, you can pass an existing form class to modelform_factory.

Comment: You are right, it appears in the example. The full documentation on modelform_factory is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out how to add a Metaclass to MyModelBaseForm
 that will do the trick:

```
class MyModelBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class __metaclass__(forms.ModelForm.__metaclass__):
        """
        Metaclass to register the modelform with the model, 
        as model._meta.modelform.
        """                

        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dic):
            super(__metaclass__, cls).__init__(cls, name, bases, dic)
            cls._meta.model._meta.modelform = cls

    class Meta:
        model = MyBaseModel
        fields = [ ... ]
```